# Definition of subsolution in sobolev spaces

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives, linear-pde

Consider $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^{N}$ a smooth domain and
$$Lu = -\text{div}(A(x)\nabla u) + b(x) \cdot \nabla u + c(x)u,$$
a uniformly elliptic operator with $A(x) = (a_{ij}), a_{ij} \in C^{1}(\Omega), b = (b_{1}, ..., b_{N}), b_{i} \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$ and $c \in L^{\infty}(\Omega)$.

My professor gave the following definition for subsolution:

Definition: We say that a function $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$, $p > N$ is a subsolution of $L$ if
$$
(1)\,\,\, 
\begin{cases}
L u \leq u, \Omega, \text{a.e.} \\ \,\,\,\,u \leq 0,\Omega.
\end{cases}
$$

Is it right to think that the natural way to think that $u \in W^{2,p}(\Omega)$ is a subsolution of $L$ is to say that
$$
(2)\,\,\,
\int_{\Omega} (A \nabla u)\cdot \nabla \phi + (b\cdot \nabla u) \phi + (cu)\phi \leq  \int_{\Omega} f(x,u) \phi, \quad \forall \phi \in C^{1}_{0}(\Omega)
 $$
and $\gamma_{0}(u) \leq 0$ (where $\gamma_0$ is the trace operator)? If I'm right, anyone know any reference with an appropriate version of divergence theorem which I could use to get from $(2)$ to $(1)$ ?

Comment: What is $f$ in $(2)$? Also, I think in $(2)$, $b\cdot u$ should be $b\cdot\nabla u$. You need to ask your professor for a check of his definition: in my opinion, the subsolution of $Lu=0$ should be defined as $Lu\leq 0$ in a.e. $\Omega$ and $\gamma_0(u)\leq 0$ in $\partial \Omega$.

Comment: the condition $\phi\ge0$ is missing in (2).